# Updating "success_url" adds the content twice after POST method is executed

Tags: python-3.x, django

I am trying to add function which will add entries in the database, its adding the data with out any issues however, when I update the sucess_url with the page I want it to re-direct, Django duplicates the url text in the variable:

```
`class NotesCreateView(CreateView):
    success_url = 'smart/notes'
    model = Notes
    # fields = ['title', 'text']
    form_class = NotesForm`
```

It fails with Page Not found error as success_url is sent back with 'smart/notes/smart/notes' instead of 'smart/notes'.

I tried updating blank value, debugging edit.py, however, couldn't reach to the root cause of the issue.

Is there any parent class that would cause this issue?

Comment: `success_url = '/smart/notes'`

Comment: please use `reverse_lazy` instead.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you redirect/link to a path without a *leading slash* (`/`), it will append that to the current path, that is called a *relative path*.

You thus should use an *absolute* path, so:

```
class NotesCreateView(CreateView):
    success_url = '/smart/notes'
    model = Notes
    form_class = NotesForm
```

it might however be better to work with [**`reverse_lazy(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse-lazy) and thus work with the *name* of the view:

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy


class NotesCreateView(CreateView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy('view-name')
    model = Notes
    form_class = NotesForm
```